# Chef attribute values

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using a recipe to edit a file. If I want to edit a file I am using ruby_block resource in the recipe where the values are defined in attributes. Below is my sample recipe.

```
ruby_block 'edit conf' do
  block do
    rc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{node['Installation']['file1']}")
    rc.search_file_replace_line("Dir","Dir=#{node['Installation']['home']}")
    rc.search_file_replace_line("max","max=#{node['Installation']['log_home']}")
    rc.write_file
  end
end
```

This will search and replace certain values where the values are defined in attributes. In future if the values are changed, then I have to edit the values in attribute file. Is there any way I don't touch my recipe or attribute file and replace the values. It should be like I refer a vfile which contains sets of values which needs to be changed. Attributes or recipes picks the values from that file and replace it. So that I change the values in file anytime and recipes and attributes are not changes. Or any other thoughts.

Appreciate your help !!!

Answer (score 2):

You're heading toward a bad pattern (and problems in mid-long term) by no willing to update your cookbook attribute file and bumping the cookbook version.

You're loosing the value of versionning the cookbooks and the ability to revert if there's a problem somewhere.

Moreover it's highly discouraged to edit files, prefer managing the whole file with a template resource.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your use case correctly, but it looks like you could use [Data Bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html) for that.

For example, you can create the following data bag (`installation.json`):

```json
{
  'id': 'installation',
  'home': '/installpath',
  'log_home': 'whatever'
}
```

Then upload it to the Chef Server:

```
$ knife data bag create myapp
$ knife data bag from file myapp installation.json
```

Now you can read this information from the recipe:

```ruby
conf = data_bag_item('admins', 'installation')

ruby_block 'edit conf' do
  block do
    rc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{node['Installation']['file1']}")
    rc.search_file_replace_line("Dir","Dir=#{conf['home']}")
    rc.search_file_replace_line("max","max=#{conf['log_home']}")
    rc.write_file
  end
end
```

Hereinafter, when you want to change these values you can do the following:

```
$ knife data bag edit myapp installation
```

Note that those values will be the same for every server if everyone reads the same data bag.

Comment: Why on earth creating a node attribute from databag values ? Use the databag values directly where they're needed.

Comment: Of course, attributes are no longer necessary. Fixed. Anyway, I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: In my opinion, it's a bad pattern to edit a file and it should be managed completely. The databag approach is correct, using a role could be a solution too.

Comment: Yes, it's an antipattern and we must try to avoid it whenever possible. Totally agree with you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Earlier we used template resource where not to edit file and to manage whole file. But now the requirement is to edit the file and replace few values. I can give the input values in attributes and whenever we have new values i can edit the input values in attributes. But instead of editng  attributes or databags, I can have an external file not related to cookbook where i can mention all the values in this file and the recipes or attributes or databags refer values from this file. I can change this file any number of times and will maintain in seperate location.

Comment: OK, so you need to read the values from a external file for whatever reason although it is a bad pattern. What's the format of this file? JSON? INI? any format? You can use standard ruby libraries to read a file from the server and use that values in the recipe. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Any pattern will do. Yes i want to read any file and take values from that file and use it recipe.